# Janus GridEx for ASP.NET Designer Support

Tags: c#, asp.net, janus, gridex

I've been working with Janus GridEx for Web for a few days. I'm afraid I'm unable to open the GridEx designer (Grid context menu in ASP.NET designer), which makes real work fairly impossible or at least unproductive. I get the following error message:

> Error invoking 'GridEX Designer'. Details:Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Unfortunately this error message doesn't really tell me anything about the real error. In Janus Forums, somebody had the same issue. The support guy recommended to check version and Local Copy property, but this isn't the cause of the problem (neither mine nor the guy's in Janus Forum).

Thank you for any help.

Greets
Matthias

Answer (score 2):

Original text of this post:

> I just figured out how to open the
>   GridEx designer. Visual Studio needs
>   to be running as Administrator ("Run
>   as Administrator" in Vista, and
>   confirm the UAC message). Don't like
>   that personally, but it works fine.

This is right so far, the message does not appear anymore. The designer did open, but did not save any changes. In Janussys forum, support staff had not seen this behavior before.

Currently the problem is different (I'd say even worse): The designer does not open, but the message mentioned in the opening post doesn't appear anymore. Just nothing happens. UAC is still disabled, and Visual Studio running as Administrator. I completely reinstalled the component with UAC disabled.

I know that "Doesn't work!" is no proper error description at all, but in this case I just don't know better.

Comment: Dont mean to bring up such an old post but I seem to be having the same problem and was wondering if you ended up finding a solution?